# How do you free up gpu memory?

Tags: python-2.7, gpu, gpgpu, theano

When running theano, I get an error: not enough memory. See below.
What are some possible actions that can be taken to free up memory?
I know I can close applications etc, but I just want see if anyone has other ideas. For example, is it possible to reserve memory?

> THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32 python 
>   conv_exp.py Using gpu device 0: GeForce GT 650M Trying to run under a
>   GPU.  If this is not desired, then modify network3.py to set the GPU
>   flag to False. **Error allocating 156800000 bytes of device memory (out
>   of memory). Driver report 64192512 bytes free and 1073414144 bytes
>   total**  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "conv_exp.py", line
>   25, in 
>       training_data, validation_data, test_data = network3.load_data_shared()   File
>   "/Users/xr/courses/deep_learning/con_nn/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/src/network3.py",
>   line 78, in load_data_shared
>       return [shared(training_data), shared(validation_data), shared(test_data)]   File
>   "/Users/xr/courses/deep_learning/con_nn/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/src/network3.py",
>   line 74, in shared
>       np.asarray(data[0], dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/sharedvalue.py",
>   line 208, in shared
>       allow_downcast=allow_downcast, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/var.py",
>   line 203, in float32_shared_constructor
>       deviceval = type_support_filter(value, type.broadcastable, False, None) MemoryError: ('Error allocating 156800000 bytes of device memory
>   (out of memory).', "you might consider using 'theano.shared(...,
>   borrow=True)'")

Comment: "you might consider using 'theano.shared(..., borrow=True)'" quoth the error message. I'd give that a shot.

Comment: Does this happen after the Theano computation has been running for a long time or during initialization?

Comment: @msw Borrow is already true. First thing checked.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw No, it's the first time I run it. But just retried it and don't get the error anymore, whereas before I was consistently getting it.

Comment: Do you no longer need this question answered? Can you provide an answer of your own?

Comment: If you changed, for example, the size of your neural network's hidden layers, then it may now be working because you're simply asking it to store fewer parameters in GPU memory.

Answer (score 3):

If borrow is set to true garbage collection is on (default true: `config.allow_gc=True`) and the video card is not currently being used as a display device (doubtful, since you're using a mobile gpu), the only other options are to reduce the parameters of the network or possibly the batch size of the model.  The latter will be especially effective if the model uses dropout or noise-based masks (these will be equal to the number of examples in the batch x the number of parameters dropped out or noised).

Otherwise maybe you could boot to the command prompt to save a few mbs?
:/