# Theano (GPU) memory footprint management / debug

Tags: python, theano

I'm using theano to do some computation involving a large (about 300,000 x 128) matrix.

The theano function quit after outputting a `MemoryError`, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936166/how-do-you-free-up-gpu-memory).

I think it's probably because the large matrix gets processed step by step, and each step leaves a large `GpuArray` (although the same shape as the first one) in the memory.

So my question is:

1. In the case of temporary(non-output) variables with the same shape and dtype, does theano make any effort to reuse such allocated memory? like, a pool for each array shape exist?
2. If 1, can I inspect which node in the function graph reuses memory?

Although I know there's [shared](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/compile/shared.html) that can do explicit sharing, but I'm in doubt that using it would make the (already hard) computation code harder to understand.

**UPDATE**

A simplified example of such situation:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T

a0 = T.matrix()  # the initial 

# op1 op2 op3 are valid, complicated operations,
# whose output's shape are identical to a0's
a1 = op1(a0)
a2 = op2(a1)
a3 = op3(a2)

f = theano.function([a0], a3)
```

If none of op1, op2, op3 can be optimized as in-place,
will theano try to reuse memory, e.g. `a1` and `a3` might "share"
the same address, to reduce memory footprint, since `a1` is no
longer used at the time of `op3`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use in-place operations as much as possible. For the most part this is not under user control (they are automatically used by the optimizer when circumstances allow) but there are a few things you can do to encourage their use.

Take a look at the documentation on this issue:

- [memory profiler](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/profiling.html)
- [Information on the optimizations that enable in-place operation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/optimizations.html)
- [How to create custom operations that can work in-place](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/inplace.html)

Do not use the `inplace` parameter of the `inc_subtensor` operation, as indicated in the [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#indexing). The [docs also indicate](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#inplace) that inplace operators are not supported for user specification (the optimizer will automatically apply them when possible).

You could use Theano's [memory profiler](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/profiling.html) to help track down which operation(s) are using up the memory.

**UPDATE**

I'm not an expert in this area but I believe Theano uses a garbage collection mechanism to free up memory that is no longer needed. This is discussed in the [documentation.](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/faq.html#faster-theano-function)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very nice and detailed, Now I know another option (make an inplace operation) :). I've updated my question, would you please take a look?

Comment: Thanks again! the GC mentioned in theano seem to be inter-call, not in a single theano function call.